# PowerMockito.whenNew is Working with Reference not working with Object

Tags: powermock

I was trying understand Test following scenario where First creation of map should be mocked and second instance creation of should not be mocked and i have written in following way which is working one scenario and not working in later scenario ,

```
public class A {

  public void test(){
    Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    Map<String,String> map1 = new HashMap<String, String>();
    System.out.println(map);
    System.out.println(map1);
  }
}
```

First Way of writing Test which is working as expected

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(A.class)
public class ATest {

    @Test
    public void test() throws  Exception{
        HashMap<String,String> map = PowerMockito.mock(HashMap.class);
        HashMap<String,String> hashMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
        PowerMockito.whenNew(HashMap.class).withNoArguments().thenReturn(map,hashMap);
        A a = new A();
        a.test();
    }


}
```

Second way where I passed new HashMap() directly, which throwing exception,

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(A.class)
public class ATest {

    @Test
    public void test() throws  Exception{
        HashMap<String,String> map = PowerMockito.mock(HashMap.class);
        PowerMockito.whenNew(HashMap.class).withNoArguments().thenReturn(map,new HashMap<String,String>());
        A a = new A();
        a.test();
    }


}
```

can anyone please let me know why it is not working when I pass HashMap Directly.....?

Comment: does the same happen when using method chaining? ie `.thenReturn(map).thenReturn(new HashMap<String,String>())`

Comment: @Nkosi  with method chaining all instances are assigned mock HashMap, There is no effect of chaining/adding second thenReturn

Comment: what is the exception thrown.

Comment: @Nkosi
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.UnfinishedStubbingException: 
Unfinished stubbing detected here:
-> at ATest.test(ATest.java:23)

E.g. thenReturn() may be missing.
Examples of correct stubbing:
    when(mock.isOk()).thenReturn(true);
    when(mock.isOk()).thenThrow(exception);
    doThrow(exception).when(mock).someVoidMethod();
Hints:

Comment: the [`thenReturn` method definition](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/blob/46a54bddaeedcd8d11287fa6055514694da2bb03/powermock-api/powermock-api-mockito-common/src/main/java/org/powermock/api/mockito/internal/expectation/DelegatingToConstructorsOngoingStubbing.java#L45) require `final` parameters and you are trying to assign a new object that can be assigned multiple times. The same error would occur if you were to do `.thenReturn(new HashMap<String,String>());`. As you have already seen, passing a variable is the recommended approach, as also shown in the examples in the exception.

Comment: @Nkosi Method is making final all the parameters , but parameters/reference variable which we are passing are not final right...?

Comment: I did not understand your last comment. can you rephrase it.

Comment: @Nkosi consider Mock that I've created is not final, still it is working.., our variables/references/objects need not be final

Comment: @Nkosi This has nothing to do with the parameters being marked as final. When you mark a parameter as final, this causes the _compiler_ to stop you from modifying it _inside_ your method. It imposes no additional requirement on the arguments passed to such a method, and it will not cause an exception at runtime. Some developers consider it good practice to mark all parameters to their methods final – as with final local variables, this helps make sure they are not accidentally modified. The calling code is not affected.

Comment: @O.O.Balance noted. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In your second test, you are violating the order constraint imposed by Mockito's validation system. Mockito validates whether you are using its methods correctly, and throws an `UnfinishedStubbingException` if you are not.

```
PowerMockito.whenNew(HashMap.class).withNoArguments().thenReturn(map,new HashMap<String,String>());
```

First, the call to `whenNew()` executes. This causes Mockito to intercept all subsequent calls to `HashMap::new`. However, you have not actually told it what to return (the `thenReturn()` part has yet to run) yet, so it is now invalid to call the `HashMap` constructor. If you do, you will encounter the exception.

Let's look at the `thenReturn()` part now. After it completes, you can safely invoke `HashMap::new` once again – Mockito will know what to return. But before `thenReturn()` gets called, all its arguments must be resolved. This causes the `HashMap` constructor to be invoked too early – hence the exception. When it is called, you have left Mockito in an invalid, intermediate state with regards to `HashMap::new`. So it throws an exception.

In contrast, your first test is fine, because you are instantiating the `HashMap` before Mockito has been told to intercept the call.